# How to reverse PHP array in partitions

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 8692
        [name] => d
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 8691
        [name] => c
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 8690
        [name] => b
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [id] => 8689
        [name] => a
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [id] => 8500
        [name] => d
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [id] => 8499
        [name] => c
    )
    [6] => Array (
        [id] => 8498
        [name] => b
    )
    [7] => Array (
        [id] => 8497
        [name] => a
    )
)
```

This array is quite long so I only included the first 4 items to give you an idea.

My problem is that I need the array to be in a format of

```
a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d
```

At the moment the format is like:

```
d,c,b,a,d,c,b,a
```

By this I mean the ['name'] value which is either a,b,c or d.

So I every 4 items in the array need to be reversed.

I have tried to achieve this but fail every time ending up with lots of for & while loops.

Comment: `array_merge([], ...array_map('array_reverse',array_chunk($data, 4)))`

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `array_chunk`, `array_merge` and `array_reverse`:

```
$finalArray = array();

$arrays = array_chunk($myArray, 4);

foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $finalArray = array_merge($finalArray, array_reverse($array));
}
```

Comment: Yep. Was writing the same thing :)

Comment: This gave me an array that looked like : Array
(
    [name] => a
    [id] => 8689
)  with no more items in

Comment: Please note that I changed `array_slice` with `array_chunk`

Comment: works a charm now! :) wish i thought of coding like this. I always go for loops and try to manually create a new array

Answer (score 3):

All the answers here, while perfectly valid, are pretty much on the order of `O(n^2)`. So I figured I'd give you an `O(n / 2)`, time complexity, solution as an alternative just in case you care about performance. The solution also uses only `O(n + n + k)` space complexity (*in place swap*).

Since the requirement is to reverse order of values, I'm ignoring keys and basing the solution on the constraint that the array is always 0-indexed.

To solve this problem, we can generalize the solution as a simple array reverse, which requires a simple `O(n/2)` operation with in-place swap. We can achieve this simply with two counters, `$i` starting from the beginning of the array, and `$j` starting at the end of the array. Thus, we can swap the values at `$arr[$i]` with that at `$arr[$j]` and then increment `$i` and decrement `$j`, at each step.

```
function reverseArray(Array $arr) {
    for($i = 0, $j = count($arr); $i < $j; $i++, $j--) {
        $tmp = $arr[$j];
        $arr[$j] = $arr[$i];
        $arr[$i] = $tmp;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Now, to apply the more *specific* solution of only reverse every group of 4 elements in the array, we just break up the array in partitions of 4 values, and only reverse each of those partitions at a time. Which just expands on the example above of `reverseArray()` by altering the starting and ending positions of the `$i` and `$j` counter to only reverse within each partition.

Thus we arrive the `O(n / 2)` solution here by just adding another loop for the partition size, and keep the inner loop from the earlier example.

```
function reverseArrayPartition(Array $arr, $partitionSize = 4) {

    $end = count($arr);

    // reverse only one partition at a time
    for($start = 0; $start < $end; $start += $partitionSize ) {

        $from = $start;
        $to   = $start + $partitionSize - 1;

        for($i = $from, $j = $to; $i < $j; $i++, $j--) {
            // swap the transposing values
            $tmp     = $arr[$j];
            $arr[$j] = $arr[$i];
            $arr[$i] = $tmp;
        }

    }

    return $arr;

}

$arr = [4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1];
var_dump(reverseArrayPartition($arr)); // expected [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

This will work with any array size at any `$partitionSize` so it's efficient if you're trying to do this on very large arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate the array with a `for` and increment with 4 each time and keep the current offset in other variable and use `array_slice` to get the current slice of array and reverse order using `array_reverse`

I am thinking of something like this:

```
$step = 4;
$offset = 0;
$new_arr = []; //Here we create the new array.
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i+=$step) {
   $part_of_array = array_slice($arr, $offset, $step);
   $part_reverse = array_reverse($part_of_array);
   $new_arr = array_merge($new_arr, $part_reverse);
   $offset += $step;
}
print_r($new_arr); //Here will be the array as you expected.
```

All the content in the for can be simplify to:

```
   $new_arr = array_merge($new_arr, array_reverse(array_slice($arr, $offset, $step)));
   $offset += $step;
```

Answer (score -1):

Not harcoding every 4, reverse based on char code of `name` value

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
/**
*/
$in = [
     ['name'=>'d','id'=>1]
   , ['name'=>'c','id'=>12]
   , ['name'=>'b','id'=>13]
   , ['name'=>'a','id'=>14]
   , ['name'=>'d','id'=>15]
   , ['name'=>'c','id'=>16]
   , ['name'=>'b','id'=>17]
   , ['name'=>'a','id'=>18]
];

$last = PHP_INT_MAX;
$toReverse = [];
$out = [];
foreach ($in as $value) {
    $p = ord($value['name']);
    if ( $p < $last ) {
        //echo 'ToReverse',var_export($value,true),"\n";
        $toReverse[] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $out = array_merge($out,array_reverse($toReverse));
        //echo 'Join',var_export($out,true),"\n";
        $toReverse = [$value];

    }
    $last = $p;
}
$out = array_merge($out,array_reverse($toReverse));
print_r($out);
```